# Use Java 7 to compile my project but use Java 8 to run my tests in Gradle

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, junit

Currently I am deploying my war to a `weblogic` server that supports `java 7`, but would like to take advantage of `Java 8` in my selenium and `Junit tests`.

How would I go about specifying in my Gradle build to use `1.7` to compile and build my `WAR` while run my tests using `1.8`?

Comment: What is your Gradle build is doing? You should post required information to make sure it's working or define the problem. AFAIP it's unclear what are you asking.

Comment: Are you asking how to build Java8 code with a Java7 compiler?!?!

Comment: I think he means build with jdk 1.7 and run tests with jdk 1.8 (implying that the source level is at 1.7)

Comment: my bad... re-read the question and you are right, he means building java8 with jdk7 : "would like to take advantage of Java 8 in my selenium and Junit tests"

Answer (score 0):

Split the sources and the tests into 2 modules.
Then, specify each module's source&target level:

```
allprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

Building with JDK1.8 will produce a jar/war for 1.7. Just override this for your test-project and set it to 1.8.

Check this: [compiling-a-project-with-different-java-source-compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190614/compiling-a-project-with-different-java-source-compatibility)

Comment: check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190614/compiling-a-project-with-different-java-source-compatibility